# How to make getline command work in a while loop?

Tags: c++

I use getline command in a while loop. The command works fine in the first loop. But after the second loop, it just passes the getline commands and doesn't allow me to enter

I tried cin.get and cin.getline but the problem is not fixed

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


int price;

void addItem(){
    string product;
    cout << "Please enter product's name: " << endl;
    getline(cin, product);
    cout << "Please enter product's price: " ;
    cin >> price;
    cout << "You have added " << product << " with a price of $" << price << " to your cart." << endl;
}

int main() {
    char answer = 'y';
    int total = 0;
    while (answer == 'y'){
        addItem();
        total += price;
        cout << "Do you want to add another product (y/n)? " ;
        cin >> answer;
    }
    if (answer != 'y'){
        cout << "Your total is $" << total << endl;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to mix `cin >> ...` and `getline(cin, ...)`. That's where the problem is. The reason it's a problem is that `cin >> ...` **does not read newlines**. So you type 'y' followed by newline but only the 'y' is read. The newline isn't read until you get to the next `getline`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
while(cin>>answer && answer !='y'){
    cout<<"enter again \n";
}
cout<<"ok";
```

Comment: Try explaining your snippet

Comment: it will execute the getline command an test if there is an input or not

Comment: It doesn't compile, as you've implicitly changed the type of `answer`. You're also not deailing with whitespace in `answer`.

Comment: getline always reads a string

Comment: try while(cin>>answer) instead if you want to read a char

Comment: @NajmeddineLouhichi Well exactly `getline` reads a string but the OPs code `answer` is a char, And your other suggestion `while (cin >> answer)` just has the same problem as the OPs code, which is the mix of `getline` and `>>`.

Comment: @john thanks now i understand the problem. Can't we just use getline in the while loop like in my first answer and the just test the value of the string answer if it contains or not 'y'

Comment: @NajmeddineLouhichi That seems reasonable as long as you make it clear that this does something slightly different from what the original code does.

Comment: @NajmeddineLouhichi It would seem slightly simpler for the OP to just remove getline and use >> thoughout.

Comment: yes i agree. Thanks for the comments

Comment: I tried this `while(cin>>answer && answer !='y')` but the code didn't compile. I also tried `getline(cin, answer)` instead of `cin >> answer` but the code automatically break after the first loop although the input is 'y'

Answer (score 0):

Mixing `cin >>` with `getline(cin,...)`, so you should to avoid it. I assume that you used `getline` to read product name which contain spaces inside. You could rewrite your code to use only `getline` which should give you expected behavior:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


int price = 0;

void addItem(){
  string product{};
  string price_str{};
    cout << "Please enter product's name: " << endl;
        getline(cin, product);
    cout << "Please enter product's price: " ;
    getline(cin,price_str);

    /*CHECK IF price_str is number before calling stoi*/

    price = stoi(price_str);
    cout << "You have added " << product << " with a price of $" << price << " to your cart." << endl;
}

int main() {
    string  answer = "y";
    int total = 0;
    while (answer == "y"){
        addItem();
        total += price;
        cout << "Do you want to add another product (y/n)? " ;
        getline(cin,answer);

    }
    if (answer != "y"){
        cout << "Your total is $" << total << endl;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I have found a solution for this. I add `cin.ignore()` after `cin >> answer` and it works perfectly.